# Using Rails and Redis to create multiple jobs

Tags: ruby, redis

I am new to redis and have not been able to find any guides to create what I have in my head. I want to create multiple Jobs each doing a simple process.

Job one: Generate a new, random number between 1-100 every 10 seconds. Job two: Keep a running total of the sum of Job one. Job three: Generate a new, random letter from the English alphabet once every 30 seconds.

If anyone knows a simple script that could help me achieve this little problem it would be a great help.

I don't really know where to begin.  This ( http://redis.io/commands/rpoplpush ) might be a good resource but I'm not sure which commands will be best to use.  Any help would be much appreciated.

-Vishnu

Answer (score 2):

From my experience with background jobs and Ruby, I strongly recommend using [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq). It uses Redis to manage the queues, but you don't have to worry about it rpoplpush or any Redis command. Sidekiq does it for you.

Now, it seems that you have **three kind of jobs**, and job 2 **depends** on job 1. You have several approaches to keep a running total of the sum of job one, but for dependency between jobs I would suggest this [SuperWorker](https://github.com/socialpandas/sidekiq-superworker).

If you get stuck on writing the actual code, come again and I am sure it will be easier to help you. But Sidekiq should be a good starting point to manage jobs in Ruby.